# Firestore ngIf interpolation

Tags: firebase, frontend, google-cloud-firestore

I have the firebase collection named vehicles:[image: Firestore document]
Each document has the same fields. I want to print only those documents that are available. The `available` field is `boolean` type. If I do some operation then the `available`will change to `false`.

So I am importing the `vehicles` collection to my component:

```
  export class VehiclesComponent implements OnInit {

  vehiclesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Vehicle>
  vehicles: Observable<Vehicle[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.vehiclesCollection = afs.collection('vehicles')

    this.vehicles = this.vehiclesCollection.valueChanges()
    console.log(this.vehicles.subscribe(function(val) { console.log(val.map(function(x) { x.avaiable }))}))

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And now I want to print documents only with `available` field set to true:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles | async">
  <div *ngIf="{{vehicles.avaiable}}">
    {{ vehicle.brandOfCar }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I am getting following error:

```
`compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("

<ng-container *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles | async">
  <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="{{vehicles.avaiable}}">
    {{ vehicle.brandOfCar }}
  </div>
  ...
   `
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do the interpolation like this `*ngIf="{{vehicles.avaiable}}"`

Try without curly braces.

```
*ngIf="vehicles.avaiable"
```

And if you only want to show the vehicles that has `true` value do it in the query like this

```
this.vehiclesCollection = afs.collection('vehicles', ref => ref.where('avaiable', '==', true))
```

Then it will only download the items you want to show. and don't forget to add the indexes.